# Toast not displaying in android

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to display the Toast at the center. When there is no Google Play Service installed then I want to redirect to the Google Play Service and display the Toast.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

    context = this;

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.install_google_play_service), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.gms")).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }
```

Comment: `runOnUiThread` will run your given code in differnt thread

Comment: @Shushant Updated question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

I removed the flag on the intent.

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.gms")));
```

Comment: It's best practice to invoke another app using the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK so that if user leaves your app when he was on the Play Store and comes back again after a significant period of time, he is not take to Play Store directly which will be the Activity in your Tasks stack. You can create an Intent before invoking startActivity supply the same in the call.

Answer (score 4):

From your `runOnUiThread()` below the toast, I assume this is being run on a different thread. Toasts are part of the UI, so it needs to be run on a UI thread.

Just move all your `Toast` code inside the UI thread and it should work fine.

Comment: No there still not working..I move inside the runOnUiThread()

Comment: I see no reason it shouldn't show with your updated code. Are you *sure* that `resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS`? You might want to log it or step through with a debugger.

Comment: Yes. It redirecting me to the Google Play Service but no Toast. I am directly running app not debugging

Comment: I think enable notifications in app settings.It might be disable